# how to use logic in jquery

Tags: jquery, wordpress

i am only read tutorials of jQuery but now how to used the conditions in it. i have html form with php and ajax.
All is work well data show on frontend when click the options

1)i want to do when the page is full load then show the random video .

2)when user enter keyword and select the type then again call to ajax.
First priority on change(select item from options) and second priority is keypress.

when user change the value from option section then call to ajax(it is work aleady)

additional

when keypress then click the mouse anywhere(but selected item is important) then call to ajax.

when the page is refresh auto call to ajax and select the random videos

this is my html form

```
<form> 
 <input type="text" name="psrn" id="prsnvl"> 
 <select id="prsnchs"> 
   <option value="0">Action/option>
    <option value="1">Drama</option>
    <option value="2">Horror</option>
  </select>
```

this is my own script code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   $('#prsnchs').on('click', function(e){

        e.preventDefault();
        var ajax_url = plugin_ajax_object.ajax_url; // i did declare in main plugin file 
        
        // fetch the record with parameters
        var data ={
          action: 'myaction', // it is my plugin ajax request
          adSlct: $('#prsnchs').val(),    
        };
   
        $.ajax({
            url: ajax_url,
            type:'post',
            data: data,
             success: function(response){
                $('#dyanmic-content').html(response); // it is sent on the front end
          },
     })
  })
```

Comment: you should do `$('#prsnchs').on('change'`

Comment: thankyou, i will changed but auto call the ajax when the page is refresh

Comment: you should create another function that will do that, then call it on page load and also in the `change` event

Answer (score 0):

You should do `$('#prsnchs').on('change'` instead of `$('#prsnchs').on('click'`.

Create another function that you should call everytime those 2 happens.
Example below:

Calling `getRandomVideos()` will do what you want.

```
function getRandomVideos(){
    var ajax_url = plugin_ajax_object.ajax_url; // i did declare in main plugin file 
        
    // fetch the record with parameters
    var data ={
      action: 'myaction', // it is my plugin ajax request
      adSlct: $('#prsnchs').val(),    
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: ajax_url,
        type:'post',
        data: data,
        success: function(response){
            $('#dyanmic-content').html(response); // it is sent on the front end
        },
     });
}

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $('#prsnchs').on('change', function(e){

        e.preventDefault();
        
        // when changing select update
        getRandomVideos();
        
    });

    // when page is loaded
    getRandomVideos();
    
});
```